# How to map a long bash command in vim?

Tags: shell, vim, call

The shell command can kill chrome process.

```
ps -ef | grep chrome |awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill
```

Now I want to map the character `-` with above bash command.

```
nnoremap  -  :!ps -ef | grep chrome |awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill
```

It takes no effect, how to map my bash command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Escape the pipes

Every pipe has to be escaped. Then append it with `<CR>` so you don't have to press enter all the time.

```
nnoremap - :!ps -ef \| grep chrome \|awk '{print $2}'\| xargs kill<CR>
```

## Kill'Em All

Note also, that we have a cute little tool to kill'em all. So instead of

```
ps -ef | grep chrome |awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill
```

you can do

```
killall chrome
```

Your mapping then will be

```
nnoremap - :!killall chrome<CR>
```